# The Number of Ways of Distributing Balls

Tags: combinatorics

According to the book which I am reading, "If the balls are indistinguishable we can calculate the number of different ways to place three balls in four boxes to be just four, and the number of ways to place three balls in five boxes to be just 20. In general, there are *M!/N!* ways to place *N* indistinguishable balls in M boxes, with at most one ball in each box (*M ≥ N* must still be true)." I think the formula is not correct. I think in the case of 3 indistinguishable balls and 5 boxes the answer is 10. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Are the boxes indistinguishable?  If they are distinct, then there are more than $4$ ways to place the balls.  If they are indistinguishable, then I only see three ways, namely $\{3,0,0,0\}, \{1,2,0,0\}, \{1,1,1,0\}$.  Am I forgetting one?

Comment: @lulu You overlooked the restriction that only one ball may be placed in each box, which is understandable since it is stated after the formula is given rather than before.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Ah!  really have to hunt for that.  Thanks, that was indeed my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ways of distributing $k$ indistinguishable balls to $n$ distinct boxes with the restriction that at most one ball may be placed in each box is 
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
since we must choose which subset of $k$ boxes will receive a ball.  In the case of $3$ indistinguishable balls and $5$ distinct boxes, our formula yields $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ as you found.

The number of ways of distributing $k$ distinct balls to $n$ distinct boxes with the restriction that at most one ball may be placed in each box is 
$$\binom{n}{k}k! = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$$
since we must choose which $k$ of the boxes will receive a ball and then distribute the balls to those boxes.